# Create user inside a transaction

Tags: servicestack

When creating a user like so:

```cs
using var trans = Db.BeginTransaction();
AuthRepository.CreateUserAuth(newUser, request.Password);
AuthRepository.AssignRoles(created, new List<string> { request.role });
//.. do other stuff
throw new Exception("other code may throw this");
trans.Commit();
```

The Auth repo has it's own connection so it's not part of the transaction.  This means, if my code bails out, I end up with an unwanted user.

Is there any way to use a transaction with AuthRepository or is only way to manually write to user and role tables?  I couldn't find an example of creating the password hash in docs when manually saving, is there any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the existing Auth Repository APIs within a transaction because each uses its own DB connection.

If you want you can take the implementation of those OrmLite Auth Respository APIs in [OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs) and move them into your method so they're all using the same DB Connection + Transaction.

Also note that to use [Transactions in OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#transaction-support) you should use `OpenTransaction()` instead, e.g:

```
using (var dbTrans = db.OpenTransaction())
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding class I used here in case it helps anyone as needed a little refactoring:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OutReachPete.ServiceModel.User;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Auth;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;

namespace OutReachPete.ServiceInterface.User
{
    public class UserHelper
    {
        public static bool ForceCaseInsensitiveUserNameSearch { get; set; } = true;
        public static bool UseDistinctRoleTables { get; set; } = true;

        public static UserAuthCustom CreateUserAuth(UserAuthCustom newUser, string password, IDbConnection db)
        {
            newUser.ValidateNewUser(password);

            AssertNoExistingUser(db, newUser);

            newUser.PopulatePasswordHashes(password);
            newUser.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            newUser.ModifiedDate = newUser.CreatedDate;

            db.Save(newUser);

            newUser = db.SingleById<UserAuthCustom>(newUser.Id);

            return newUser;
        }

        public static void AssertNoExistingUser(IDbConnection db, IUserAuth newUser,
            IUserAuth exceptForExistingUser = null)
        {
            if (newUser.UserName != null)
            {
                var existingUser = GetUserAuthByUserName(db, newUser.UserName);
                if (existingUser != null
                    && (exceptForExistingUser == null || existingUser.Id != exceptForExistingUser.Id))
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(ErrorMessages.UserAlreadyExistsTemplate1,
                        newUser.UserName.SafeInput()));
            }

            if (newUser.Email != null)
            {
                var existingUser = GetUserAuthByUserName(db, newUser.Email);
                if (existingUser != null
                    && (exceptForExistingUser == null || existingUser.Id != exceptForExistingUser.Id))
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(ErrorMessages.EmailAlreadyExistsTemplate1,
                        newUser.Email.SafeInput()));
            }
        }

        public static UserAuthCustom GetUserAuthByUserName(IDbConnection db, string userNameOrEmail)
        {
            var isEmail = userNameOrEmail.Contains("@");
            var lowerUserName = userNameOrEmail.ToLower();

            UserAuthCustom userAuth = null;

            // Usernames/Emails are saved in Lower Case so we can do an exact search using lowerUserName
            if (HostContext.GetPlugin<AuthFeature>()?.SaveUserNamesInLowerCase == true)
            {
                return isEmail
                    ? db.Select<UserAuthCustom>(q => q.Email == lowerUserName).FirstOrDefault()
                    : db.Select<UserAuthCustom>(q => q.UserName == lowerUserName).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            // Try an exact search using index first
            userAuth = isEmail
                ? db.Select<UserAuthCustom>(q => q.Email == userNameOrEmail).FirstOrDefault()
                : db.Select<UserAuthCustom>(q => q.UserName == userNameOrEmail).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userAuth != null)
                return userAuth;

            // Fallback to a non-index search if no exact match is found
            if (ForceCaseInsensitiveUserNameSearch)
            {
                userAuth = isEmail
                    ? db.Select<UserAuthCustom>(q => q.Email.ToLower() == lowerUserName).FirstOrDefault()
                    : db.Select<UserAuthCustom>(q => q.UserName.ToLower() == lowerUserName).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return userAuth;
        }

        public static void AssignRoles(IAuthRepository userAuthRepo, IUserAuth userAuth, IDbConnection db,
            ICollection<string> roles = null, ICollection<string> permissions = null)
        {
            if (userAuthRepo is IManageRoles managesRoles)
            {
                AssignRoles(userAuth.Id.ToString(), db, roles, permissions);
            }
            else
            {
                AssignRolesInternal(userAuth, roles, permissions);

                SaveUserAuth(userAuth, db);
            }
        }

        public static IUserAuth GetUserAuth(string userAuthId, IDbConnection db)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAuthId))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userAuthId));

            return db.SingleById<UserAuthCustom>(int.Parse(userAuthId));
        }

        public static void AssignRoles(string userAuthId, IDbConnection db, ICollection<string> roles = null, ICollection<string> permissions = null)
        {
            var userAuth = GetUserAuth(userAuthId, db);
            if (!UseDistinctRoleTables)
            {
                if (!roles.IsEmpty())
                {
                    foreach (var missingRole in roles.Where(x => userAuth.Roles == null || !userAuth.Roles.Contains(x)))
                    {
                        if (userAuth.Roles == null)
                            userAuth.Roles = new List<string>();

                        userAuth.Roles.Add(missingRole);
                    }
                }

                if (!permissions.IsEmpty())
                {
                    foreach (var missingPermission in permissions.Where(x => userAuth.Permissions == null || !userAuth.Permissions.Contains(x)))
                    {
                        if (userAuth.Permissions == null)
                            userAuth.Permissions = new List<string>();

                        userAuth.Permissions.Add(missingPermission);
                    }
                }

                SaveUserAuth(userAuth, db);
            }
            else
            {

                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var userRoles = db.Select<UserAuthRole>(q => q.UserAuthId == userAuth.Id);

                if (!roles.IsEmpty())
                {
                    var roleSet = userRoles.Where(x => x.Role != null).Select(x => x.Role).ToHashSet();
                    foreach (var role in roles)
                    {
                        if (!roleSet.Contains(role))
                        {
                            db.Insert(new UserAuthRole
                            {
                                UserAuthId = userAuth.Id,
                                Role = role,
                                CreatedDate = now,
                                ModifiedDate = now,
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!permissions.IsEmpty())
                {
                    var permissionSet = userRoles.Where(x => x.Permission != null).Select(x => x.Permission).ToHashSet();
                    foreach (var permission in permissions)
                    {
                        if (!permissionSet.Contains(permission))
                        {
                            db.Insert(new UserAuthRole
                            {
                                UserAuthId = userAuth.Id,
                                Permission = permission,
                                CreatedDate = now,
                                ModifiedDate = now,
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private static void AssignRolesInternal(IUserAuth userAuth, ICollection<string> roles, ICollection<string> permissions)
        {
            if (!roles.IsEmpty())
            {
                foreach (var missingRole in roles.Where(x => userAuth.Roles == null || !userAuth.Roles.Contains(x)))
                {
                    if (userAuth.Roles == null)
                        userAuth.Roles = new List<string>();

                    userAuth.Roles.Add(missingRole);
                }
            }

            if (!permissions.IsEmpty())
            {
                foreach (var missingPermission in permissions.Where(x =>
                    userAuth.Permissions == null || !userAuth.Permissions.Contains(x)))
                {
                    if (userAuth.Permissions == null)
                        userAuth.Permissions = new List<string>();

                    userAuth.Permissions.Add(missingPermission);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void SaveUserAuth(IUserAuth userAuth, IDbConnection db)
        {
            if (userAuth == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userAuth));

            userAuth.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (userAuth.CreatedDate == default(DateTime))
                userAuth.CreatedDate = userAuth.ModifiedDate;
            
            db.Save((UserAuthCustom)userAuth);
            
        }

    }
}
```

Then just call it like:

```cs
var created = UserHelper.CreateUserAuth(newUser, request.Password, Db);

UserHelper.AssignRoles(AuthRepository, created, Db, new List<string> { request.CreateUserType.ToString() });
```

It will only use the connection passed.  Just change `UserAuthCustom` to whatever you user class is.